# How to get a second element of every element in a list

Tags: python-3.x

Imagine a python list

a=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

how could I get a list out of this such that I get the elements of the list a that satisfy that the second element is bigger than 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [32]: a=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

In [33]: [s for s in a if s[1]>2]
Out[33]: [[3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I guess the result you expect with your example is:

`result=[[3,4], [5,6]]`

In that case you'd just need to do:

`result=[l for l in a if l[1]>2]`

This is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).